# Update seconds dropdown based on the selection of the first dropdown using the database

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

I have two dropdowns in my HTML. The second select would change depending on the selection of the first one. I want my first element to be the one to make an AJAX call and extract what's inside of my database. I am not quite fluent in jQuery/AJAX and I need help on this one. Here is an example:

```
          <select name="menu">
            <option value="meat"> Meat </option>
            <option value="seafood"> Seafood </option>
            <option value="vegetarian"> Vegetarian </option>
            <option value="dessert"> Dessert </option>
          </select>



          <select name="entrees">
            {% for i in meat %}
            <option value='{{idx.0}}'> {{i.1}} </option>
            {% endfor %}

                    //more loops for other menu
          </select>
```

When the user select the type of food, different entrees appears on the second html dropdown. I am using python and django in  my backend. The entrees are being updated regularly that is why I can't hardcode the options of the second dropdpwn, as many have suggested on some question here.

LET'S SAY:
I choose 'meat.' How do I make an ajax call to get all the meat entrees in an array so I can loop into it? I would greatly appreciate it if you can comment lines that are important so I can learn something new.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: you can find an example here https://tutorialzine.com/2011/11/chained-ajax-selects-jquery

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this only by Django without page reload. For some dynamic updates you have to use Javascript.
The simple way is to use jQuery with some backend endpoint (which actually have to return some JSON with entrees):

```
<select name="menu" id="menu">
  <option value="meat"> Meat </option>
  <option value="seafood"> Seafood </option>
  <option value="vegetarian"> Vegetarian </option>
  <option value="dessert"> Dessert </option>
</select>

<select name="entrees" id="entrees">
  // display only first category
  {% for i in meat %}
    <option value="{{ idx[0] }}">{{ i[1] }}</option>
  {% endfor %}
</select>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
      const MENU_ITEM = $('#menu'),
        ENTREES_ITEM = $('#entrees');
      MENU_ITEM.on('change', function() {
        const value = MENU_ITEM.val()
        $.ajax({
          // request settings
        }).then(function(response) {
            // remove all options
            ENTREES_ITEM
              .find('option')
              .remove();

            // append new options
            $.each(response.data.entrees, function(i, item) {
              ENTREES_ITEM.append('<option value="' + i + '">' + item + '</option>');
            })
        })
      })
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Hello, where in this code am I sending a backend request and which part returns me a json object?

Comment: request settings - is you params(url, data):
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Your case will contain something like this:

    $.ajax({
      url: '<some_your_backend_url>',
      dataType: 'JSON',
      data: {menu: value}
    })


and backend endpoint:


`def some_endpoint(menu_value):`
        `return json.dumps({'entrees': ['option1', 'option2', 'option3']})`